# Wrong node removed when using removeFromParent in spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

I want a node to be removed from parent after it makes contact with an object, but the node is spawned continuously, with multiples of the same node on the screen at once. The issue is, whenever the node makes contact and removeFromParent is called, it isn't removed, but another node that hadn't made contact yet is. I'm wondering what I can do to make sure that the node that is removed is the one that made contact and not a node of the same type.

Comment: Do some debugging. Use NSLogs to find which nodes are having contact. We can't do anything to solve this problem if there is no code and no specific details.

Comment: When I put in the NSLog it prints out the name of the bar since I detect contact through name rather than contactbitmasks. The nodes are responding to the contact, its just the wrong node that is removed. Do you think this might happen because I detect contact through contact.bodyA.node.name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to make each instance unique. One way to do this is to assign a unique name to each node instance. First you need to create a counter:

```
@property (nonatomic) int myCounter;
```

Then you use the counter as part of a node's name:

```
myCounter++;
myNode.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myNode-%i",myCounter];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the nodes to self as childs. Add them to another node you make. Then you could use this line of code to remove all of the nodes within the bigger node:

```
bigNode.addChild(smallNode) //Add smallNode to bigNode instead of self
bigNode.removeAllChildren() //Removes all of the smallNodes since they all are children of bigNode
```